Gemini AI error - "AttributeError: module 'google.generativeai' has no attribute 'GenerativeModel'"
I am trying to create a script in Jupyter for testing Google Gemini AI model.
import google.generativeai as genai
import os

# genai.configure(api_key="API Key")

model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
response = model.generate_content('Please summarise this document: ...')

print(response.text)

I'm getting this error:
AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 6>()
      2 import os
      4 # genai.configure(api_key=os.environ['API_KEY'])
----> 6 model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
      7 response = model.generate_content('Please summarise this document: ...')
      9 print(response.text)

AttributeError: module 'google.generativeai' has no attribute 'GenerativeModel'

I tried:

Re-installing package - python3.11 -m pip install google-generativeai
Checked whether the class named GenerativeModel existed in my installed package source code but it didn't help.

Python and package versions:

python: 3.11.7
google-generativeai=0.5.1


I find it best to check the source - seems to be where you expect it to though (https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python/blob/e09e7f242abcabe1bda28168be58a751ccdc5c03/google/generativeai/generative_models.py#L24)

Looks like it's a known issue on older version. Might be relevant

@Gugu72 they don't appear to be using langchain.

uninstall the package and install it again.  pip install --upgrade pip then
pip install google-generativeai --upgrade   the current version is 0.5.2 so you dont have the right version at the very least.

I'm having the same issue as you, a fix that you may or maynot be able to implement is downgrading your python version back to 3.10 in which gemini seems to be working without any issues.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This worked for me !

The class should exist since v0.3.0 (https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python/commit/098854379496247617ef7fea882694022fca171d)
You must be using an older version of the SDK.
There are two likely causes:

You've installed the package to a different environment than the one you're actually using. If you use Jupyter, please use the %pip install magic to install packages.
You have updated the package, but have not restarted the Jupyter session.

